# test_first string indices must be integers

Tags: python, dictionary, integer, indices

I created a dict from keywords for searching them from text file. My code below prints out right answer, but tmc test result says: "string indices must be integers". What should I change?

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
def word_frequencies(keywords):

    with open ("src/alice.txt", 'r') as f:
        
        alicE = f.readlines() 
        d = defaultdict(int)
        templist = []
        word_count = []
        for line in alicE:
            line = line.split()
            for word in line:
                word = word.strip("""!"#$%&'()*,-./:;?@[]_""")
                word.title()
                if word in keywords:
                    d[word] += 1
                else:
                    continue
        for key, value in d.items():
            templist = key, "\t", value, "\n"
            word_count.extend(templist)
            
    search_list = ''.join(map(str, word_count))
    return search_list       
    
        
            
def main():
    pass
    keywords = ['The', 'Project', 'Gutenberg', 'EBook', 'of', 'creating']
    print(word_frequencies(keywords))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I can't tell anything unless you tell me what's in the .txt file

Comment: `but tmc test result says: "string indices must be integers". What should I change?` seems like in your tmc test code you are inadvertently treating some string variable as a dictionary and indexing it with a string instead of an integer. Can you please verify that?